# How to show caret in Android 2.3 in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, android, android-2.3-gingerbread

Currently when I have following HTML code in web page:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
Some content
</div>
```

and view it via Android-2.3, I don't see caret.

It exist but is invisible because when I long-press menu button (to force soft keyboard),
I can input characters into that div.

So, does anyone know how to force show caret inside that div?

Comment: This might very well be a bug in Android and as a result, not easy or even impossible to resolve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [blog post on contenteditable in mobile WebKit](http://www.symphonious.net/2010/09/13/contenteditable-in-mobile-webkit/), this is a bug in the Android / WebKit source. Considering that [it was reported as a bug report in July 2010](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9512), it doesn't seem to have a high priority. However, WebKit is open source and you can always consider signing up and fixing the bug yourselves.

This effectively prevents using editors such as TinyMCE, CKEditor, YahooUI from a mobile device, or at least, you won't be able to see the caret. Sorry that I don't have better news.

PS: I noticed that it is also not possible [to select text in a ContentEditable field](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9513), which is a related bug.

PPS: not sure whether it is possible to use JavaScript to get the caret position. If it is possible, you might be able to mimic the behavior of a caret by drawing a vertical line and let it blink. Maybe this is what Google Docs did to make it working on the Android?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to mimic the behavior of a caret